# Universal analytics Code of Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

There is a guide that describes how to split the code of Google Analytics.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/#SplitSnippet
The idea is as follows:
Declare the object for GA at the head of the HTML document.
Load the JavaScript library at the bottom.
All the measurement data is preserved and sent.

Everything is described in the documentation linked to this question.
You may actually find it useful to speed up load time of your websites
- especially mobile ones.

I would like to know how to do it with the new universal analytics code.

Thanks in advance for any links or answers.

Answer (score 0):

The analytics.js snippet is part of [Universal Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/)

Look at the above link. It will clarify your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet developed by [Local Wisdom](http://www.localwisdom.com)

http://www.localwisdom.com/blog/2013/09/global-google-analytics-event-tracking-script/

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
window.ga = window.ga || function(){};
```

I took it from the original tracking code (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) snippet:

```
(function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
  i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
  i[r] = i[r] || function() {
    (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
  }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
  a = s.createElement(o), 
  m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
  a.async = 1;
  a.src = g;
  m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
```

which does basically the same check

```
i[r] = i[r] || function() {
   …
  }
```

i is the window object and r the name for the analytics function name. Both get passed when the function invokes itself

```
(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
```

In general the analytics code itself is loaded asynchronously anyway, so it shouldn´t hurt to much if you have it in the header.

Update: I found the proper way to load google analytics on localhost while not sending test data in here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced, for localhost use the following code:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {
   'cookieDomain': 'none'
});
```

(Old: I had to check / define 'ga' because in my local development environment I do not load the analytics code at all and so I would get a reference error.(